# Default condition in UML sequence diagram

Tags: uml, conditional-statements, sequence-diagram

I just created a sequence diagram that describe the log-out process.
I started with making an actor lifeline called "dosen" that accessing "log out page".

How do I describe in that sequence diagram that user has logged in before he accessing log-out page?

[image: Image of Sequence Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

You can place a note on the diagram. It is not necessary to describe everything formal. A constraint for example is best described with a short note.

On a side note: log out page does not seem to be an instance. Use only instances on sequence diagrams! The reason is simply that classes do not interact. Only their instances will. (And if I guess that you're using EA you run in trouble when not doing so!)

Comment: Okay, thanks man!

But I don't understand the side note you described. At the very right lifeline, I put "dosen" which is an object from class "dosen". In PHP, it will be : $dosen = new dosen{}

Comment: `dosen` is an object and correct that way.  But `log out page` has no colon. So it's likely a class. And that is not correct.